# Widget Actions onClick and onUpdate with separate function by instance

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget

**UPDATE: SOLVED**
[Android Widget - Click for action, update under 30 minutes, separate instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824817/android-widget-click-for-action-update-under-30-minutes-separate-instances)

Correction of answer with code:

[Android Widget - Click for action, update under 30 minutes, separate instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824817/android-widget-click-for-action-update-under-30-minutes-separate-instances)

I need help for coding a widget (in the example Widget is the widget activity and Configuration the configuration activity). I need only the widget class code.

Widget:

- Every tot seconds do an AutoUpdate (for name and color)retrieving the data from a routine on Configuration Activity (Example: Every 5 Seconds widget call Configuration.GetData(...))
- On click widget must call another procedure (Example: Configuration.execute()) and then do an AutoUpdate.

All must works in multiple instances (So i have to pass appWidgetId to all routine)
I've already the Configuration activity that works fine (SharedPreferences with appWidgetId identifier)

I've readed so much answers and tutorial but during coding i've that problem on widget:

First attempt:
-All works fine with only one instance, but from the second i cannot correctly get appWidgetId (all widget works like the latest)

Second attempt:
-onUpdate (with alarmManager) works fine for the first instance then all the instances self AutoUpdate on their time and on other instance time...
-Button click does nothing
Other Attemp between the first and second are a mix of all the problems.

Comment: Please provide the smallest amount of code which illustrates your problem.

Comment: You've posted a nice list of your requirements. Now all you need to do is post your efforts to start coding to meet them, and ask a *specific question* about the problem you're having with that code, and we might be able to help you get an answer. Good luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824817/android-widget-click-for-action-update-under-30-minutes-separate-instances

Comment: Please don't edit your question to say **SOLVED**. If you want to post an answer, improve your question so that it gets reopened and then post an answer to it properly. You can even accept your own answer as the correct one after a period of time has passed. The [faq] has more info about answering your own questions here; it's completely proper to do so. Thanks.